# Ionic Cordova Background mode is not working, how to resolve?

Tags: angular, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework, rxjs

I am trying to include Cordova background mode in my app however everytime I import it into my app.module.ts, I recieve this error in my console.

```
[ng] ERROR in node_modules/@ionic-native/background-mode/index.d.ts:2:10 - error TS2305: Module '"C:/Users/Loraine/Documents/prod-safe-mzansi/safe-mzansi-free/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Observable'.
[ng] 2 import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
[ng]            ~~~~~~~~~~
[ng] node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts:1:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/Observable'.
[ng] 1 export * from 'rxjs-compat/Observable';
[ng]                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

my cordova version is 8.0

and this is snippets from my app.module.ts file

```
import { BackgroundMode } from '@ionic-native/background-mode';

providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    AuthenticateService,
    Geolocation,
    InAppBrowser,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
    Contacts,
    AndroidPermissions,
    SMS,
    CallNumber,
    AppLauncher,    
    Shake,
    BackgroundMode
  ],
```

I have looked at all articles about this and there does not seem to be much about this problem, I havve tried installing and reinstalling the module, I have uninstalled Cordova 9.0 and reinstall Cordova as 8.0

Also have tried including as

```
import { BackgroundMode } from '@ionic-native/background-mode/ngx';
```

However it then get this error.

```
Cannot find module '@ionic-native/background-mode/ngx'.
```

Does anyone have a solution to doing background tasks with ionic or keeping the app in the background.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem,
I installed several different dependencies,

$ npm install --save @ionic-native/background-mode@4 
$ cordova plugin add https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode.git

just do in your src dir, npm uninstall @ionic-native/background-mode@4

and also cordova plugin remove https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode.git

Comment: i am facing the same problem .

Comment: Can You Give me clear instruction? what commends i need to run ?